# How to retrieve all the parameters listed under r_basicprofile permission for a linkedin user using linkedin api?

Tags: rest, permissions, linkedin-api

I am working on **sign in with linkedin** feature on my web app. I want to store all the information listed under r_basicprofile permission for the users who sign up. I followed OAuth 2.0 and have got the response but the api returns only the basic details like firstname, lastname, profile.

I have the following permissions for my app.
[image: permissions]

I got the following response from the api `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`
[image: response]

I want to access all the fields listed for `r_basicprofile` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply for Partner program if they will approved then you can use r_basicprofile's all field

In V2 you can use :

r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

r_emailaddress for getting emailAddress - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation where the necessity to "enrol in the partner program" has been mentioned?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

"Looking to maintain access to the Basic Profile fields? Learn more about applying to a LinkedIn Partner Program."

Comment: @ErvinKalemi Thanks!